# Get post contents of wordpress using CURL

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

How to get the post contents of single post of wordpress using cURL ..

I have to tried to get the blog contents using Rss Feed . but i want to get the single post content by passing the **post_url**

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes It is possible through two methods.

1. [WordPress REST API](https://github.com/WP-API/client-php)
2. [XMLRPC](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API)

I tried with XMLRPC to create post in wordpress blog from third party CMS, I am not sure about rest api, but there could be a way in the documentation.

Comment: i want to get post content from third party website. Is ther any way to do that .. Can u plz share some examples

Comment: @user8025 You can't get the post content of third party website through these methods. If you really want to do it then its a bit tricky to get the only content of the post.

Comment: Can u suggest any plugin?

Comment: @user8025 I don't think so if any plugin exists, Will update if i found something relevent to this.